# my .pop() function affects multiple lists, do i need to store the first list in another way?

Tags: python, list

I try to save a new list with the variables of an old list, and then .pop() the last item from the new list without affecting the old list.

```
new = ['Bram', 'Glenn', 'Menno']
old = ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']

print('new1', new)
print('old1', old)
new = old
print('new2', new)
print('old2', old)
new.pop()
print('new3', new)
print('old3', old)
```

this gives the output:

```
new1 ['Bram', 'Glenn', 'Menno']
old1 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
new2 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
old2 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
new3 ['Glenn', 'Menno']
old3 ['Glenn', 'Menno']
```

But I would like the output:

```
new1 ['Bram', 'Glenn', 'Menno']
old1 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
new2 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
old2 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
new3 ['Glenn', 'Menno']
old3 ['Glenn', 'Menno', 'Eefke Maria']
```

Is it the way I store my list variables?

Comment: Variables only store references to objects. "new = old" creates a new variable with a reference to the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a `copy` for your list check this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/18317391:

```
new = old.copy()
```

Comment: commenting here as this is the correct answer. another option:

new = list(old)